# constructor SomeClass() is already defined in class SomeClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I just upgraded my Spring Boot 1.5.13 application (with Lombok) to Spring Boot 1.5.14 but it now fails to compile with the following types of errors:

```
constructor SomeClass() is already defined in class SomeClass
```

for each of my POJOs, e.g.,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass {
    private String someProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a bug in Lombok 1.6.22; upgrade Lombok to 1.18.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or, as a work-around, change the order of the annotations:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SomeClass {
    private String someProperty;
}
```

**Details:**

The root cause of this bug is a bug in Lombok 1.16.22. Spring Boot 1.5.13 uses Lombok 1.16.20 which does not have this bug, but Spring Boot 1.5.14 updated the Lombok dependency to 1.16.22 -- unfortunately, the Lombok project does not comply with [SEMVER](https://semver.org/) which then triggered this bug.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue even on the most recent version i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After marking my member variables as final everything worked.

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with the required arguments, where a required arguments are final fields and fields annotated with `@NonNull` (more on that later)

Comment: As a matter of fact this will happen with AllArgConstructor or RequiredArgsConstructor if there's also Data OR NoArgConstructor AND there's no fields that match AAC/RAC preferences. For example, if you put AAC and NAC on a subclass without it's own fields.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the same issue using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
</dependency>
```

And, in my case, it was conflict between `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation and `@Data`.

As it turned out later:

> @Data implies @NoArgsConstructor

So, [the advice](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1863#issuecomment-422279788) for removing the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation, but leaving `@Data` was helpful for me.